# how do you use Direct2D to render ClearType text on a transparent background?

Tags: c#, direct2d, sharpdx, cleartype

can anyone tell me why ClearType is picking up the transparency of the background in the simple SharpDX sample below? And how to stop it from doing that.

it renders two lines of solid black text into a semi-transparent bitmap. the first line is rendered with Grayscale, and the second is rendered with ClearType.

**EDIT**: it has been suggested that the problem is that the surface is pre-multiplied. but that doesn't explain the difference between the two Grayscale/ClearType renderings.

result (win7):

[image]

```cs
public static void Main()
{
    var pixelFormat = SharpDX.WIC.PixelFormat.Format32bppPBGRA;

    using (var wicFactory = new ImagingFactory())
    using (var dddFactory = new SharpDX.Direct2D1.Factory())
    using (var dwFactory = new SharpDX.DirectWrite.Factory())
    using (var textFormat = new TextFormat(dwFactory, "Arial", FontWeight.Bold, FontStyle.Normal, 48))
    using (var textLayout = new TextLayout(dwFactory, "argle-bargle", textFormat, float.PositiveInfinity, float.PositiveInfinity))
    {
        var width = (int) Math.Ceiling(textLayout.Metrics.Width);
        var height = (int) Math.Ceiling(textLayout.Metrics.Height);

        using (var wicBitmap = new SharpDX.WIC.Bitmap(
            wicFactory,
            width, height * 2,
            pixelFormat,
            BitmapCreateCacheOption.CacheOnLoad))
        {
            var renderTargetProperties = new RenderTargetProperties(new SharpDX.Direct2D1.PixelFormat(Format.B8G8R8A8_UNorm, AlphaMode.Premultiplied));
            Color4 textColor = new Color4(0f, 0f, 0f, 1f);

            using (var renderTarget = new WicRenderTarget(dddFactory, wicBitmap, renderTargetProperties))
            using (var textBrush = new SolidColorBrush(renderTarget, textColor))
            {
                renderTarget.BeginDraw();
                renderTarget.Clear(new Color4(1f, 1f, 0f, .25f));

                renderTarget.TextAntialiasMode = TextAntialiasMode.Grayscale;
                renderTarget.DrawTextLayout(new Vector2(0, 0), textLayout, textBrush);

                renderTarget.TextAntialiasMode = TextAntialiasMode.Cleartype;
                renderTarget.DrawTextLayout(new Vector2(0, height), textLayout, textBrush);

                renderTarget.EndDraw();
            }

            var path = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), "test.png");
            using (var stream = File.OpenWrite(path))
            {
                using (var encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder(wicFactory, stream))
                using (var frameEncoder = new BitmapFrameEncode(encoder))
                {
                    frameEncoder.Initialize();
                    frameEncoder.WriteSource(wicBitmap);
                    frameEncoder.Commit();
                    encoder.Commit();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This behavior is expected since your surface is pre-multiplied (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd368058(v=vs.85).aspx). You should explain what you are really expecting.

Comment: I'd expect the grayscale and cleartype renderings to be consistent. What if you can't create a non-premultiplied surface?

Answer (score 1):

This unexpected result is a "normal" behavior.

As it stands in MSDN:

> If you specify an alpha mode other than D2D1_ALPHA_MODE_IGNORE for a
>   render target, the text antialiasing mode automatically changes from
>   D2D1_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_MODE CLEARTYPE to D2D1_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_MODE
>   GRAYSCALE.

So, your first assignment of the `renderTarget.TextAntialiasMode` to Grayscale is pointless, because `Grayscale` is its initially setted value.

Another quote from MSDN:

> You can use the SetTextAntialiasMode method to change the text
>   antialias mode back to D2D1_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_MODE CLEARTYPE, but
>   rendering ClearType text to a transparent surface can create
>   unpredictable results. If you want to render ClearType text to an
>   transparent render target, we recommend that you use one of the
>   following two techniques.
>
> - Use the PushAxisAlignedClip method to clip the render target to the
>     area where the text will be rendered, then call the Clear method and
>     specify an opaque color, then render your text.
> - Use DrawRectangle to draw an opaque rectangle behind the area where the text will be rendered.

Here is the full article: [D2D1_ALPHA_MODE enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd368058(v=vs.85).aspx)

So, if I have to summarize:

1. Don't set `D2D1_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_MODE_CLEARTYPE` to a render target with alpha mode different from `D2D1_ALPHA_MODE_IGNORE`
2. Follow the techniques from above.

Comment: thanks. so basically the answer is that you can't: neither of the 'alternative' techniques described yield the desired results. I guess the only way to do it is to render to a separate bitmap and do the alpha blend manually.